# Best practice to store large string in SQL Server using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for best practice to store list of string into database using Entity Framework Core.

My data is a set of roles maybe about 100 roles or more,  so I have two options:

1. Use another table and make some relationship.
2. Use one column type `nvarchar(max)` and separate roles by `;`

I need to know which way is better and why?

For now my code using the option 2 to store data and Entity Framework value converter to convert from list to string with `;` separator and vice versa.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(c =>
    {
        c.Property(f => f.Roles).HasConversion
        (
            v => String.Join(";", v),
            v => v == null ? new List<string>() : v.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
        );
    });

}
```

Comment: You should ***never ever*** store multiple values into a single database cell - it violates even the **first normal form** of database design - **don't do it!** The proper way to handle this in a relational database **is** to have a separate table for this - go for this approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely data modelling point of view, absolutely need to split it up into multiple rows in a separate table. There are so many types of queries this will allow that a single string will not

This is regardless of whether you use Entity Framework or anything else.

Comment: but what if i have 1,000,000 user and each one have 100 roles ?   
i d'ont any queries just fetch the roles and split it to list in my application ...

Comment: Answer will be driven by the associated question - do you ever need to query on roles? If the answer is yes, then it should be a table. If its really just a single long string then store it however you like. But it *sounds* like data, and therefore should be treated as data, no matter how big it is.